# MVC3 & Ajax : Refresh list to hide a record which was deleted from list by a button click

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a list which displays Subscribed forums threads and with in each row there is a button to un-subscribe. I works fine using Ajax to unsubscribe, but I want to refresh using Ajax to remove unsubscribed thread from the list. Can anyone please suggest me. My code is as below:

Idea behind using Ajax is because I just want to refresh the list section not entire page.

**Index.aspx**

```
<% foreach (var thread in Model.threads) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%: thread.Title %></td>
        <td><%: Ajax.ActionLink("Unsubscribe", "ToggleForumAlertFromList",
                    new { id = thread.ForumId },
                    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", 
                        UpdateTargetId = "none", 
                    new { ID = "togglealertlink" })%>
        </td> 
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ToggleThreadAlertFromList(Guid id)
{
    // Do stuff to unsubscribe        
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

Comment: Seems like this would work, though why you're using aspx forms instead of cshtml views in MVC 3 is beyond me.  Are you having a particular issue?  Is something throwing an error or not working?

Comment: I suspect this should really be a POST, not a GET. Easiest would be to use `$.post()` to pass the id, then in the method return json indicating success, and in the success callback, just remove the associated item (`<tr>` element) from the DOM (no need to update the whole list again)

Comment: @StephenMuecke it IS a post, both as declared in the ActionLink and on the api.

Comment: Your right - just saw `Ajax.ActionLink` and assumed it was a GET :)

Comment: @DavidL I know cshtml works better, but we are using some third party controls which only works with aspx views.

Comment: @Scorpion Fair enough, sometimes you're constrained :).  That said, what is the actual problem that you are running into?  Are you getting an error?  How can we actually help you?

Comment: @DavidL it is working, but I want to refresh the list so that specific record can be removed from the list. Currently it is not refreshing it and unsubscribed records stays there until whole page is manually refreshed.

Comment: what I want is that when button is clicked, it should sunsubscribe it (which is working) and also it should remove the record from list without refreshing whole page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wire in an OnSuccess callback that fires when your POST completes.

This callback can either requery your list or simply remove the un-subscribed item from your list.

```
<% foreach (var thread in Model.threads) { %>
    <tr id= "<%: thread.ForumId %>">
        <td><%: thread.Title %></td>
        <td><%: Ajax.ActionLink("Unsubscribe", "ToggleForumAlertFromList",
                    new { id = thread.ForumId },
                    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", 
                        UpdateTargetId = "none", 
                        OnSuccess = "removeItem('thread.ForumId')"
                    new { ID = "togglealertlink" })%>
        </td> 
    </tr>
<% } %> 

function removeItem(itemId) {
    $("#" + itemId).remove();
}
```

This assumes that each parent `<tr>` element has been assigned a unique forumId as shown above.